# CSS Grid repeat with max width defined by child's content?

Tags: css-grid

I have a grid container of dynamic width, with an unknown number of children. These children will have a varying and unknown amount of text within them.

I know it's possible to make the number of columns dynamic:

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 150px));`

However the CSS above sets the minimum width of each column to be 100px and the maximum to be 150px. Is it possible to have no maximum and instead let this be defined by the child elements text content?

I tried this but it actually makes the columns smaller:

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, auto));`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have tried grid and it isn't working as expected, you can use flex instead,

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
/* 
 you can add some max-width to the children elements
*/
.wrapper > div {
  max-width: 50%; /*Any other with will work*/
  width: 100px; /* the min width of the div */
}
```

Comment: I need vertical columns when the content wraps. This is why I used Grid as Flexbox doesnt support this.